# Fragment href reloads page / generates wrong URL

Tags: html

I stumbled onto something odd that I cannot explain.

Take this page here:
http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained/

In the contents there are links that are fragment anchors - they only contain the URL fragment in the `href` attribute.

Yet for some reason the whole link points to a location that is different than the current pathname. The difference is 1 capital letter, but pathnames are case sensitive, therefore it technically points to a different page.

What is happening here?

I've been able to reproduce this behaviour across browsers (well, blink and firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the head of the page, you find the following base-tag: 
`<base href="http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/Rogue-unchained/">`, which defines the capitalized URL as base URL.

According to MDN, the base URL is also used for anchors:

> Anchor tags within a page, e.g. anchor, are resolved by using the base URL as the reference and trigger an HTTP request to the base URL.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: Jeez. That answers this conundrum. But what is the purpose of the base tag? I can't figure out any actual use case for it.

Comment: Its purpose is to specify the base URL for all relative URLs used on the page. I can't find a good example for a use case though.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for your help.